# Disable jquery calling in Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, e-commerce

I've added `Qbanner` to my homepage and all works correct. In `Chrome developer console` I see that it trying to call `jquery.1.5.1.js`, but I searched in ALL project code and did not find any reference to this script. Where i should find it? I do not need this jquery because of conflicts.

Here is the screen shot
[chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzwdg.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check the layout xml of `Qbanner` extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `app\code\community\Qaz\Qbanner\Block` open `Qbanner.php`.

replace the

```
  public function _prepareLayout() {
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        $headBlock->addJs('qaz/qbanner/jquery.1.5.1.js');
        $headBlock->addJs('qaz/qbanner/jqueryNoconfig.js');
        $headBlock->addJs('qaz/qbanner/jquery.slides.min.js');

        $headBlock->addCss('qaz/qbanner/css/global.css');
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

with the below

```
public function _prepareLayout() {
    $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    $headBlock->addJs('qaz/qbanner/jqueryNoconfig.js');
    $headBlock->addJs('qaz/qbanner/jquery.slides.min.js');

    $headBlock->addCss('qaz/qbanner/css/global.css');
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: there's no $headBlock->addJs('qaz/qbanner/jquery.1.5.1.js') in Qbanner.php

Comment: is this your extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/q-banner-slider.html?

Comment: yes it is.  this is my _prepareLayout:                                                                   public function _prepareLayout() {
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        $headBlock->addCss('qaz/qbanner/css/global.css');
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

Comment: I just download it from the given url. and found `$headBlock->addJs('qaz/qbanner/jquery.1.5.1.js')` in `app\code\community\Qaz\Qbanner\Block\Qbanner.php.`

Comment: try to clear your cache and reindexing. it might solve your problem

Comment: is it your actual webaddress `cascade-magento-ee`?

Comment: try to rename jquery.1.5.1.js

Comment: there's no such file (jquery.15.1.js) in directory  /js/qaz/qbanner/ and i don't need to use this jquery

Comment: ohh!! then i think either you hitting wrong url or there is such a big mash stupid thing you miss

Comment: i'm very foolish man, and made a simple mistake, forgetting to remove the reference to jquery from layout updates in cms-page (admin). thank you for taking part in solving the problem!

Comment: Glad to know. Congrats. :)

Comment: @dd_ramone : if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this